# How to auto-fill select box in rails 4?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my form, I have a select box like

```
<%= f.select :form_name, get_form_names, { }, { class: 'selectpicker', required: true }  %>
```

I have another select box `<%= f.select :form_fields %>`.
Now when the user selects the `form_name`, I want to populate the options for `form_fields` select box based on the name of the form.

I wrote a new method in my controller to get `form_fields`

```
def get_form_fields
  @fields = (params[:form_is].constantize).column_names
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

and in my `routes.rb`

```
get 'export_from_form/get_form_fields'
resources: export_from_forms
```

And I tried the following JS to get form fields data

```
$(function(){
  $("#export_from_form_form_name").on('change', function(){
    var form_name = $("#export_from_form_form_name:selected").val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "get_form_fields",
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'script',
      data: { form_is: form_name},
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
        console.log("AJAX Error: " + errorThrown); 
      },
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        console.log('Dynamic column slect OK!  ' + data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**EDIT**
**Now I am able to get an array of form_fields as a json encoded array. But regardless of what I try I can't append this array as options for**

```
<%= f.select :form_fields,[], { prompt: "Select Column names" }, { :multiple => true, class: 'selectpicker', required: true }  %>
```

This is my js:

```
$(function(){
  $("#export_from_form_form_name").on('change', function(){
    var name =$("#export_from_form_form_name").val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "get_columns",
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: { form_is: name},
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ console.log("AJAX Error: " + errorThrown); },
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        console.log(data);
        change_select(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
function change_select(data) { 
    $("#export_from_form_form_fields").empty();//remove all previous majors
    var length = data.length;
    for(i = 0;i<length;i++){ 
        $("#export_from_form_form_fields").append(//add in an option for each major
            $("<option></option>").attr("value", data[i]).text(data[i])
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide additional information on how you want to populate the second select box?. Maybe post your whole form code?

Comment: Maybe use plain javascript to do that ... or do you want to send a request each time someone selects the form name?

Comment: @TonyVincent You need to use JS for this.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Please see my edits. Plese help me figure out what changes I need to make

Comment: @mahatmanich I added the JS i tried, please guide me to make the required changes

Comment: Don't do Ajax call, to fetch option values. Do it in memory using JS like I said above. Ajax call is not needed. Ajax call will make this slow, not correct approach in this case. You can load all options when you loaded the page, then write JS and let your JS handle this dependent dropdown lists.

Comment: @TonyVincent I already posted an answer. That is correct and working. Read the answer, understand it and implement it. But Ajax approach is bad in this case.

Comment: @ArupRakshit the values I want to populate have to be fetched from database. Any thoughts ??

Comment: You can fetch those values when you load the page, no? Like using Rails `select` helper etc?

Comment: @ArupRakshit Much appreciate your help sir, but its just that your assumption "OP knows or already have dropdowns loaded with correct option values" simply doesn't fit. Thanks for pointing out the drawbacks of using AJAX

Comment: @TonyVincent You can discuss that with me, and I am not sir, I am just a developer and struggles also at work when I don't know something. Then I do discuss with people, and then think accordingly. Instead of doing this, what you did is not appreciated. Anyway, I would consider now that you know how to populate dropdown values when page load, right?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to demonstrate this using a simple example. I hope this will enable you think the problem in right direction.

```
<label> Select a color: </label>
<select id="colors">
  <option value="">Please Select a color</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>

<hr/>

<label> Select a Fruit: </label>
<select id="fruits">
  <option value="cherries" data-color="red">Cherries</option>
  <option value="cranberries" data-color="red">Cranberries</option>
  <option value="strawberries" data-color="red">Strawberries</option>
  <option value="limes" data-color="green">Limes</option>
  <option value="honeydew" data-color="green">Honeydew</option>
  <option value="avocados" data-color="green">Avocados</option>
</select>
```

And here is the required jquery

```js
var $fruit = $("#fruits");
var $color = $("#colors");
var $fruitValues = $fruit.find("option").clone();

$fruit.empty().append('<option value="">Please Select a Fruit</option>');

$color.change(function(event) {
  var options,
    selected = $(this).val();

  $fruit.find('option').not("option:first").remove();
  if (selected.length === 0 || selected === void 0) return false;

  $fruitValues.filter(function(index, element) {
    return $(element).data('color') === selected
  }).appendTo($fruit);
});
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m7wo67oq/11/).

This answer only focused to explain that how you can make 2 dropdowns dependent using plain JS. I assumed OP knows or already have dropdowns loaded with correct option values. Once those 2 dropdown field will be loaded in page using normal rails page load, this JS can action on it and emits the expected result.

Comment: Forgive me for my ignorance, do you really think its a better idea to load all form_fields prior to selecting form_name ??